# Save checkboxes of a metabox with a foreach loop (invalid argument)

Tags: metabox, save-post, php

I'm new to Wordpress plugin development and I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes (from a WP Query) to associate as custom fields for a specific post type. Nothing wrong with the display function, but when I'm trying to save I get the error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

How can I check what the save function sees in my global array `$loop_brands`? Someone can helps me to solve and understand?

```
<?php

function brands_display_meta_box( $post ) { 

    global $loop_brands;
    $loop_brands = array();

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'brands-nonce-field' );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 7,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $query_brands = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($query_brands->have_posts()) : $query_brands->the_post(); 

        $id_brand = get_the_ID();
        $brand = get_post($id_brand, ARRAY_A);
        $slug_brand = $brand['post_name'];
        $titolo_brand = $brand['post_title'];

        $loop_brands[] = $slug_brand;

?>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>" name="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>" value="yes" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, $slug_brand, true ), 'yes' ); ?>>
            <label for="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>"><?php echo $titolo_brand; ?></label>

        </p>

<?php endwhile;

}

function brands_add_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'brands-meta-box',
        'brands Meta Box',
        'brands_display_meta_box',
        'stores',
        'side',
        'high'
    );

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'brands_add_meta_box' );

function brands_user_can_save( $post_id, $nonce ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce ], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );

    return ! ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) && $is_valid_nonce;

}

function brands_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {

    global $loop_brands;

    foreach ( $loop_brands as $brand ) {

        if ( brands_user_can_save( $post_id, $brand ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST[ $brand ] ) ) {

                update_post_meta( $post_id, $brand, $_POST[ $brand ]);

            } else {

                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $brand);

            }

        }

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'brands_save_meta_box');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise would be to extract the query portion of your code:

```
function get_brands() {
  $loop_brands = array();

  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'brands-nonce-field' );

  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_parent' => 7,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
  );

  $query_brands = new WP_Query($args);
  return $query_brands;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
function brands_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    $loop_brands = get_brands();
    $loop_brands = wp_list_pluck($loop_brands->posts,'post_name');
    foreach ( $loop_brands as $brand ) {
        if ( brands_user_can_save( $post_id, $brand ) ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $brand ] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $brand, $_POST[ $brand ]);
            } else {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $brand);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That would be the first step. Unless I made a mistake the code should work exactly as before, but without the worry and mess of the `global`.

You can then move to a more complicated solution involving a bit of "caching" if you will:

```
function brands_query() {
  $loop_brands = array();

  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'brands-nonce-field' );

  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_parent' => 7,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
  );

  $query_brands = new WP_Query($args);
  return $query_brands;
}

function get_brands() {
  $brands = get_option('loop_brands');
  if (empty($brands)) {
    $brands = brands_query();
    update_option('loop_brands',$brands);
  }
  return $brands;
}
```

And if I am reading it right, you really only need to refresh `loop_brands` on *page* save. Something like this:

```
function save_brands($post_id) {
  $brands = brands_query();
  update_option('loop_brands',$brands);
}
add_action('save_post_page','save_brands');
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem of saving was an issue in the if statement 'brands_user_can_save' where the 'nonce' was incorrect (I should check better before posting), by the way your code is really clean and useful. The tip to create a loop function is good, I've implemented it and works fine, so many thanks :)

Comment: @Alessio : Programming jargon is saturated with acronyms, most of which I find pretty annoying, but [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is good.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your `$loop_brands` isn't carried over to the save function. So you are running `foreach` on an empty/false variable, hence the error. I would suggest saving the `$loop_brands` as a transient or an option. Here I've tried a transient. I don't think you need a  way to clear the transient because every time the metabox is loaded the transient is refreshed, therefore it should be up to date when the save routine runs. I haven't tested this, so your mileage may vary.

```
function brands_display_meta_box( $post ) { 

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'brands-nonce-field' );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 7,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $query_brands = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($query_brands->have_posts()) : $query_brands->the_post(); 

        $id_brand = get_the_ID();
        $brand = get_post($id_brand, ARRAY_A);
        $slug_brand = $brand['post_name'];
        $titolo_brand = $brand['post_title'];

        $loop_brands[] = $slug_brand;

?>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>" name="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>" value="yes" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, $slug_brand, true ), 'yes' ); ?>>
            <label for="<?php echo $slug_brand; ?>"><?php echo $titolo_brand; ?></label>

        </p>

<?php endwhile;

    set_transient( 'loop_brands', $loop_brands );

}

function brands_add_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'brands-meta-box',
        'brands Meta Box',
        'brands_display_meta_box',
        'stores',
        'side',
        'high'
    );

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'brands_add_meta_box' );

function brands_user_can_save( $post_id, $nonce ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce ], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );

    return ! ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) && $is_valid_nonce;

}

function brands_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {

    $loop_brands = get_transient( 'loop_brands' );

    if( $loop_brands ):

    foreach ( $loop_brands as $brand ) {

        if ( brands_user_can_save( $post_id, $brand ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST[ $brand ] ) ) {

                update_post_meta( $post_id, $brand, $_POST[ $brand ]);

            } else {

                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $brand);

            }

        }

    }
    endif;

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'brands_save_meta_box');
```

Comment: Now the error is gone and now I know the transient API thanks to you, but my code doesn't save the check/uncheck clicks. Probably I had to look in the save function to find the issue. Is there a way to print_r that $loop_brands inside the 'brands_save_meta_box'? Just to check if the data is passed correctly?

Comment: You save routine must be borked. Why not merge the 2 functions? And you can `die(var_dump($something));` to kill the process and dump the variable.

Comment: Thanks Helga `die(var_dump($something));`helps me a lot :)